# I already installed my Wazuh agent, but does not appears on the dashboard

Tags: wazuh

I already run the commands

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable wazuh-agent
sudo systemctl start wazuh-agent
```

after the installation, but nothing happens in the dashboard, the agent does not exist yet. the command line after run the sudo systemctl start wazuh-agent returns nothing, looking like the command was succesfull, but still nothing happens.

[I need the agent appears just like this (the agent that i want to add is a ubuntu OS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnFmE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following:

1. That the agent and the manager are on the same network
2. Make both hosts visible to each other.
3. You can try restarting the manager so that it reloads the installed agents.
4. You can check the agents installed in the manager with the following command:

   /var/ossec/bin/agent_control -l